# Rewrite code from Pandas To PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My greetings, I need to rewrite the code from Pandas to PySpark.
I'm ok with PySpark, but do not have any skill in Pandas.
Could you please tell what does the following code do?

```
potent_cases.loc[potent_cases['status']==2,'is_too_old'] = potent_cases.loc[potent_cases['status']==2,:]\
            .apply(lambda x: True if x['close_date']  < dt.now() - timedelta(2) else False,axis=1)

cases_to_create = potent_cases.loc[\
            ((potent_cases['status'] == 2) & ((potent_cases['is_too_old'] == True) |( potent_cases['manual'] == False)))|\
            (pd.isnull(potent_cases['status'])),['shop_id','plu','last_shelf_datetime']]
```

Comment: I think you forgot to include [any attempts](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) (looks like a basic `filter` and `select`, you could probably copy and past a half of that into PySpark and run) and a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48427185/8371915). Would you mind correcting this? :)

Comment: @user8371915 not really, i cannot find what does that mean `.loc[potent_cases['status']==2,:]` . And I cannot run the Pandas code (I wish I could).                         P.S. of course I'm totally ok with lambda

Comment: @AntonBondar - Really? You can't find any documentation on `loc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a df named `potent_cases`. With `loc` you go through the rows. When the column named `status` has the value = 2, then the value in the same row of the column `is_too_old` will be `True` or `False` according to the condition `x['close_date']  < dt.now() - timedelta(2)`.

Apparently the first line is necessary for the conditions of the second line. Here if the conditions are satisfied, the dataframe `case_to_create` will be created with the subset of columns `'shop_id','plu','last_shelf_datetime'`.